# Linear operator on $L^p [0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

Let $1\leq p\leq\infty $ and let $T:L^p[0,1]\to L^p[0,1]$ be a linear operator. Suppose $T (f_n)$ converges to $T (f)$ almost everywhere whenever  $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere. I want to show that  $T$ is bounded.

I tried to  do it like this with the help of Closed Graph Theorem.

Let $(f_n,T (f_n))$ be a sequence in graph of $T$ such that  $(f_n,T (f_n))$ converges to  $(f,g)$. Then $f_n\to f$ in $L^p [0,1]$ and $T (f_n)\to g$ in $L^p [0,1] $. Thus there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ converges a.e. to $f $. Now how to show  $g=T (f)$?

Comment: I might be missing something, but if you know that $(f_n, T(f_n)) \to (f, g)$ and $T(f_n) \to T(f)$, then surely uniqueness of limits implies $g = T(f)$ (a.e.)?

Comment: Sorry I have edited.

Comment: It seems to me that you have finished. Just use the assumptions.

Comment: If I use the assumption then $T (f_{n_k})$ converges a.e. to $T (f)$. But how to go back to convergence in $L^p [0,1]$ norm?

Comment: You don't have to go back to convergence in $L^p[0,1]$ norm, because you have already $T(f_n) \rightarrow g$ in $L^p[0,1]$ and $f=g$.

Comment: Please explain a bit.

Comment: Got it. $T(x_{n_k})\to g$ in $L^p[0,1]$. Thus there exists a subsequence of $(  T(x_{n_k}))$ converges a.e. to  $g$. Hence $T(f)=g$.